# How to add inline JavaScript to a wordpress tempate file

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How to add inline JavaScript to a WordPress template file?" Plus add it to every post on my page? for instance, `<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello world');</script>` would be...

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to a template is easy; just stick it within a  tag in any part of the template you want to add it to. For instance:

```
<script>alert('Hello world!');</script>
```

as an incredibly basic (and kinda messy and improper) way to demonstrate it. Any template file is just a PHP file, or in other words an HTML file with some extra PHP code thrown in.

Also, to add something to a post, you'll want to add it to the appropriate part of your Wordpress template. For instance, in the default Twentytwelve theme, that'd be the content.php file--that contains the code for a single article, and adding something to that will add it to every instance of an article on the page.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I will try tem and get back with you. Really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

To add some javascript to every post on your page just place it inside the loop.  Something like:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello world');</script>

<?php

    the_title();
    the_excerpt();

    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Would add an alert for every post on the page.  That would be pretty messy to have a popup for every post but that's the gist.

Comment: you have added `<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello world');</script>` out side of the while loop. How does it add it every post then?

Comment: I could be wrong but I dont think closing php breaks the loop.  Can you explain how its outside the loop?

Comment: No worries... I had to check to be sure.